# Package.config getting deleted while Uninstalled only package of the solution, TFS shows as it deleted

Tags: .net, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.5.4,
I have only one package inside my solution while I try to uninstall that package and reinstalled that package with some other version, TFS shows it as deleted but when I try to add it, TFS shows error that file already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a known issue,  you could take a look at below similar question:

- [Updating packages deletes packages.config in TFS](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/491)
- [Updating packages deletes packages.config in TFS 2](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4449)

According to the response from NuGet team.

> Thanks for reporting this issue. At this time we suggest **moving from
>   packages.config to PackageReference** with VS 2017 to resolve your
>   issue. You can find out more about this here:
>   https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html

If you still want to use packages.config, you could use workaround as below:

1. rename the new package.config on disk
2. undo the deletion in TFS
3. delete the old package.config restored by TFS on disk
4. rename back the new package.config on disk

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT .. your last suggested solution worked out for me..